# runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address

Tags: c++, vector

I am solving this leetcode problem [Toeplitz Matrix](https://leetcode.com/problems/toeplitz-matrix/) (check if the matrix is toeplitz or not).
I took a simple approach here and traversed the matrix to check if each diagonal satisfies the condition.

Solution code

```
bool isToeplitzMatrix(vector<vector<int>> &matrix)
    {
        // Approach 1: Checking each diagonal
        for (int k = 0; k < matrix.size() - 1; k++)
        {
            // Checking bottom triangle
            int i = k, j = 0;
            int x = matrix[i][j];
            while (i < matrix.size())
            {
                i++;
                j++;
                if (x != matrix[i][j])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int k = 1; k < matrix.size() - 1; k++)
        {
            // Checking upper triangle
            int i = 0, j = k;
            int x = matrix[i][j];
            while (j < matrix[0].size())
            {
                i++;
                j++;
                if (x != matrix[i][j])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But on submission, I am getting this unknown error.

```
Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebeca for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_vector.h)
0xbebebebebebebeca: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9
```

why am i getting this runtime error? Please explain.

Comment: Incrementing an index *after* you determined its validity doesn't seem like a great idea.

Comment: the matrix is not square but your code assumes that it is

Comment: What's line 1034 in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error appears because you are accessing out of bound elements in the following lines:

```
i++;
j++;
if (x != matrix[i][j])
{
   return false;
}
```

You are incrementing `i` and `j` before accessing the vector. If `i == matrix.size() - 1` the condition of the while loop is true and `i` is incremented. Therefore you are accessing an element which is not in the matrix.